# Efficient way to send an image over socket in Java

Tags: java, image, sockets, javax.imageio

I'm a bit of a Java noob, and I have read some basics about sockets and I can successfully send images over socket using ImageIO, but I want to reduce the amount of data that is sent. Ultimately I want the image (screen capture) to be send as fast as possible with the smallest possible file size.

Right now, I have imageIO set up as such;

```
DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

ImageIO.write(captureImg(),"JPG",client.getOutputStream());
```

And the receiver:

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(server.getInputStream()));

File outputfile = new File("Screen"+(date.toString())+".jpg");

ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
```

In case you're wondering, this is my method that is used to take the image.

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());              
BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
```

I have heard about Byte arrays, where you can send the bytes then draw the image at the other end. However I'm not sure if this is more efficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please ask if you would like me to add any extra info or code for the byte array!

Thanks.

EDIT: Patrick:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bScrn = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ImageIO.write(captureImg(), "JPG", bScrn); 
byte imgBytes[] = bScrn.toByteArray();


out.write((Integer.toString(imgBytes.length)).getBytes());
out.write(imgBytes,0,imgBytes.length);
```

Comment: Well.. How large is each individual size at the moment? What demands do you have in terms of quality for instance? Using the jpg format will already compress the image size, but have you looked into compressing the data by zipping the stream?

Comment: btw; your title is not that explanatory of the problem, which is rather to reduce the size of an image than "send something efficient"..

Comment: Right now the images come into the server at around 150kb. The reason I'm asking as the title suggests is, is there a better way than imageIO to send an image? Because I've seen similar SO questions where a person specifically asked for imageIO not to be used, that is, the image itself isn't sent but rather the data and then the server side program draws the image and stores it. In terms of quality, they don't have to be that great, I don't have a figure on that. I have looked into zipping the images themselves but I thought I'd ask about byte arrays etc.

Comment: Uhm, zipping a JPEG won't buy you much and will waste CPU time on both sides, I'd advise against it...

Comment: Thanks, fge. I'll keep that in mind. Also, thanks Patrick for your response!

Comment: But ImageIO will send a bytestream.. what do you think the write method does with client.getOutputStream?

Comment: If this is a continous stream of images you might look into another way of compressing the image, perhaps identifying similar image regions to previous images and not send those if they are equal, and only repaint the regions that changed on the receiving end.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm using the "term" ImageIO is the wrong manner. What I meant was, simply sending a raw image verses sending it in a byte array. eg. Check my edit :)

Comment: Yes it will be a continuous stream, and there could be up to 40 people sending images at any given time.

Comment: What is the difference between "raw image" and "byte array"? To me it sounds like they would be the same.

Comment: "as fast as possible with the smallest possible file size" You need to pick one. Are you trying to keep network traffic down, or is that only because you think that will make it send faster?

Comment: Well there a different ways to send an image over socket, so I want the fastest way to send them in terms of efficiency, and to preferably have small file sizes. I apologies, my wording may be a bit off. I appreciate the replies though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already has been an extensive discussion in the comments, but to summarize a few points that I find important:

You have a trade-off between several criteria:

- Minimize network traffic
- Minimize CPU load
- Maximize image quality

You can reduce the network traffic with a high image compression. But this will increase the CPU load and might reduce the image quality.

Whether it reduces the image quality depends on the compression type: For JPG, you can make the image arbitrarily small, but the quality of the image will then be ... well, arbitrarily bad. For PNG, the image quality will stay the same (since it is a lossless compression), but the CPU load and the resulting image size may be greater.

The option of ZIPping the image data was also mentioned. It is true that ZIPping the JPG or PNG data of an image will hardly reduce the amount of data (because the data already *is* compressed). But compressing the *raw* image data can be a feasible option, as an alternative to JPG or PNG.

Which compression technique (JPG, PNG or ZIP) is appropriate also depends on the image *content*: JPG is more suitable for "natural" images, like photos or rendered images. These can withstand a high compression without causing artefacts. For artifical images (like line drawings), it will quickly cause undesirable artefacts, particularly at sharp edges or when the image contains texts. In contrast to that: When the image contains large areas with a single color, then a compression like PNG (or ZIP) can reduce the image size due to the "run length compression" nature of these compression methods.

I already made some experiments for such an image transfer quite a while ago, and implemented it in a way that easily allowed tweaking and tuning these parameters and switching between the different methods, and comparing the speed for different application cases. But from the tip of my head, I can not give a profound summary of the results.

BTW: Depending on *what* you actually want to transfer, you could consider obtaining the image data with a different technique than `Robot#createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`. This method is well-known to be distressingly slow. For example, when you want to transfer a Swing application, you could let your application directly paint into an image. Roughly with a pattern like

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w,h,type);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
myMainFrame.paint(g);
g.dispose();
```

(This is **only** a sketch, to show the basic idea!)

Additionally, you could consider further options for increasing the "percieved speed" of such an image transfer. For example, you could divide your image into *tiles*, and transfer these tiles one after another. The receiver will possibly appreciate it if the image would at least be partially visible as quickly as possible. This idea could be extended further. For example, by detecting which tiles have really changed between two frames, and only transfer these changed tiles. (This approach could be extended and implemented in a rather sophisticated way, by detecting the "minimum regions" that have to be transferred)

However, for the case that you first want to play around with the most obvious tuning parameter: Here is a method that allows writing a JPG image with a quality value between 0.0 and 1.0 into an output stream:

```
public static void writeJPG(
    BufferedImage bufferedImage,
    OutputStream outputStream,
    float quality) throws IOException
{
    Iterator<ImageWriter> iterator =
        ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter imageWriter = iterator.next();
    ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(quality);
    ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream =
        new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(outputStream);
    imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);
    IIOImage iioimage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
    imageWriter.write(null, iioimage, imageWriteParam);
    imageOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: Marco13, thanks so much for the indepth response, very much appreciated. I will most certainly look into that last piece of code you provided regarding quality.

Essentially, the program will not send images of the JFrame itself, but rather of the users screen- what ever it is that they are looking at. One image is sent every 4 or so minutes to the server.