# Sending Bufferred Image over network versus sending JPEG over network

Tags: java, image-processing

I have an application that requires images to be sent from a client to a server. 
For this operation speed and image size both need to be minimised.
Thing is, the application records at around 20 fps when i don't write the images to a file. 
However speed gets decreased to ~10 fps when i save as JPEG.

Also ironically, saving as "png" occupies only 75kb on average whereas saving as "JPEG"
requires 125 kB.

So i am a newbie when it comes to images. Should i save it as an image, or should i simply send the img
over the network.
Please help me out with the basic architecture. I have searched, but i don't get what exactly to do?
As a bonus, please give me a hint as to "how to compress an image fast". Thanks!

Comment: I recommend benchmarking the time to compress, benchmarking the time to transmit across the network and also considering multithreading - maybe with one thread receiving the data, another thread compressing it and another transmitting it across the network.

Comment: Similar questions occur frequently. I agree with Mark that you'll have to do some benchmarking. (BTW: I wrote a few more general words about such an image transfer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21969210/3182664 , maybe you'll find it interesting)

Comment: Okay. Yeah just what i was looking for. In fact i had thought about the tile by tile thing you have mentioned. Would this compromise on anything?